# Partitioning an n-set into k same-size subsets

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, set-partition

"How many ways can you partition a set of size $n$ into $k$ parts of the same size?"

I've tried solving in the following way but I'm not sure if it's correct, feedback would be appreciated. I'm new to combinatorics.

If $k$ does not divide $n$ the answer is trivially $0$. Otherwise, each part must have $\frac{n}{k}$ elements. The first of the $k$ parts can be chosen to be any $\frac{n}{k}$-subset of the $n$-set, and there are $\binom{n}{n/k}$ such subsets. The second part is a $\frac{n}{k}$-subset of the remaining $n-\frac{n}{k}$ elements, so there are $\binom{n-\frac{n}{k}}{n/k}$ subsets to choose from. Continuing in this fashion, the total number of ways to select parts becomes:

$\binom{n}{n/k}\times\binom{n-\frac{n}{k}}{n/k}\times\binom{n-2\frac{n}{k}}{n/k}\times\ldots\times\binom{{2n/k}}{n/k}$

However, since the order in which the subsets are selected doesn't matter, I have to divide by the number of permutations of $k$ parts, which is $k!$ Hence the total number of partitions becomes:

$\frac{\binom{n}{n/k}\times\binom{n-\frac{n}{k}}{n/k}\times\binom{n-2\frac{n}{k}}{n/k}\times\ldots\times\binom{{2n/k}}{n/k}}{k!}$

Is there anything wrong with this solution?

Comment: Looks good to me. But, if you express the binomial coeficients in terms of factorials, there will be lots of canceling....